# Is every hyperbolic 3-manifold of finite volume a link complement in some closed 3-manifold?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

The question says all I need to know, but I will try to clarify it a little more.

Let $M$ be a compact 3-manifold with nonempty torus boundary such that ${\rm int}(M)$ admits a complete hyperbolic metric of finite volume. Is it true that there exists a closed 3-manifold $P$ and a link $\Gamma$ in $P$ such that $M$ is diffeomorphic to the link complement $P\setminus \nu(\Gamma)$? Here, $\nu(\Gamma)$ is an open, embedded tubular neighborhood of the link $\Gamma$.

It looks to me like it might be true, because you could fill the cusp ends of $M$ via Dehn filling, generating a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold $M_2$. Then, remove a "core curve" (and here is the problem, is this well defined?) of each torus which was a boundary of the original $M$ and now lives in $M_2$, and that would be your link. However, I didn't find the reference and would appreciate any clarification about it (including counterexamples or proofs assuming, for instance, orientability).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course. You do not even need hyperbolicity, just that the boundary is a union of tori and Klein bottles.

Comment: I am fairly convinced and this generated yet a new question. How different fillings interfere in the resulting link and closed manifold? Or are they all the same? Thanks!

Comment: No idea what your new question is. Please, post it as a regular question.

Comment: I did it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153375/hyperbolic-3-manifolds-of-finite-volume-as-link-complements). Thanks!