# Hyperbolic 3-manifolds of finite volume as link complements

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

This is an improved version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146904/is-every-hyperbolic-3-manifold-of-finite-volume-a-link-complement-in-some-closed?noredirect=1#comment6489861_3146904) (sorry if I wasn't so clear there and sorry if this is well-known and I didn't find the reference).

Let $N$ be a hyperbolic 3-manifold of finite volume and let $N_1,\,N_2,\,\ldots,\,N_k$ be pairwise disjoint representatives of the cusp ends of $N$, so each $N_i$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{T}^2\times [0,\infty)$. Let $M = N\setminus (N_1\cup\ldots\cup N_k)$. Then, $M$ is a compact 3-manifold with incompressible toroidal boundary.

1) After performing Dehn filling on the cusp ends of $N$ so that the resulting closed manifold $\widehat{N}$ is hyperbolic, is there  link $\Gamma\subset \widehat{N}$ such that $N$ is diffeomorphic to $\widehat{N}\setminus \Gamma$?

2) Assuming 1) is true, how different Dehn fillings on the above procedure change $\widehat{N}$ and $\Gamma$ as above? In other words, if we produce $\widehat{N}_1$ and $\widehat{N}_2$ trough distinct Dehn fillings in $N$ are $\widehat{N}_1$ and $\widehat{N}_2$ diffeomorphic? If they are, are the links $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ isotopic?

I am trying to understand (say orientable) hyperbolic 3-manifolds (of finite volume) and the standard examples are link complements in a closed three manifold, so this question is more or less asking if for a given hyperbolic 3-manifold of finite volume there is only *one way* of seeing it topologically as a link complement. Thank you.

Comment: 1 is obviously true. Part 2 is somewhat true and somewhat false. What is true is that "most" Dehn fillings will be non-isometric, one can see this by looking at the hyperbolic volume. What papers are you reading?

Comment: Sure! Got it! Thanks @MoisheKohan. I am almost randomly reading Thurston's notes and the "3-manifold groups" book by Aschenbrenner, Friedl and Wilton. After this question, I think things are more clear in my mind.